# How to configure PhpStorm with Xdebug in remote server on docker

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I've done these steps:

1. Setup remote server for deployment in PhpStorm.
2. Setup docker server by SSH.
3. Setup file map.
4. Setup CLI Interpreter with remote docker.
5. Map port 9003 from container to remote host, and forward this port by SSH to localhost.

**Issues:**

1. "Run" test script not work with server + docker PhpStorm shows `Could not open input file:/my/t.php` message. I've tried changing path mapping to `path/to/local/script`, `path/to/remote/script`, `path/to/docker/script` and this did not do anything...
2. "Validate Xdebug" did not worked because this validator creates a test file, uploads it to the server and try run the script. But my server run scripts from directory `/pub/` but if I set this directory for upload script, PhpStorm adding `/pub/` to the URL `http://test.remote/pub` and get answer 404
3. I've tried to enable `Listen for debug connection`, enableed Xdebug extension in Google Chrome and set breakpoint on the first line, but connection was not established. Not working, I've checked 9003 port and it is allowed...
4. I've tried to create `test.php` to try debugging a CLI script, but this doesn't work too, see point 1 "run" not working.

Software versions:

1. PhpStorm - 2021.3
2. PHP - 7.4
3. Xdebug - 2.9.8

P.S. Sorry for my English.
P.P.S. I can't find manual how to setup PhpStorm, Xdebug with remote server in docker ((

Comment: *"But my server run scripts from directory /pub/ but if I set this directory for upload script, PhpStorm adding /pub/ to the URL"* That can be set up. It's a common scenario (e.g. Laravel project is served from a `public` folder).

Comment: *"Xdebug - 2.9.8"* Xdebug v2 is an old/deprecated version and no longer supported. Consider upgrading to Xdebug v3. Plus, it will be a bit easier to troubleshoot. https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide

Comment: *"Map port 9003 from container to remote host, and forward this port by SSH to localhost."* Not sure what has been done here. But I assume you use SSH tunnel here? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html If so -- are you able to connect back from inside the docker back to the IDE? The plain `telnet` (or alternative) can help here (it can simply tell if a connection was successful or not)

Comment: Sadly cannot help with anything on the actual "remote docker" part. My Docker experience is limited to a local Docker Desktop (running on Windows).

Comment: @LazyOne how to connect from server to idea with telnet?

Comment: Well, you have not provided any details on what ports you are using, but assuming it's *Reverse SSH Tunnel in use* and default Xdebug port is used then `telnet 127.0.0.1 9003` (P.S. You can also use `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` as a test -- it should connect to your local web server (so you may see the HTML from your web server). Telnet here is used to check if you can connect to the service on that IP:port. If not -- service is not running; firewall issue; wrong IP:port; other network/SSH tunnel config issue.